# jQuery selector not logical

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm having a problem selecting an specific `li` element in an un-ordered list. Although it's not a major problem and I can find a way round it, I would really like to know why it's not working.

My HTML:

```
<div id="myList">
    <ul>
        <li>something 1</li>
        <li>something 2</li>
        <li>something 3</li>
        <li>something 4
            <ul>
                <li>sub something 1</li>
                <li>sub something 2</li>
                <li>sub something 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My problem is this:

```
$('#myList ul:first li:first').addClass('cool')
```

This adds the class to the "something 1" li tag. All well and good. But:

```
$('#myList ul:first li:last').addClass('cool')
```

Instead of adding the class to "something 4" li tag, it adds it to "sub something 3" li tag.

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are selecting all li-Tags down the Tree.

You might want to try this:

```
$('#myList ul:first>li:last').addClass('cool')
```

That way you only select direct child nodes of the previous node.

Comment: Oh wow. I see my error. What a dummy. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: NP, That's why we are here - to learn from mistakes, right? Welcome to stackoverflow btw :)

Answer (score 3):

`li:last` is processed left-to-right. First, all the `li` elements that are descendants of the `ul` are selected. Because you are using a [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector) rather than a child selector, this *includes* all the "sub" `li` elements.  `:last` then selects the last of them to appear in the document, which is `sub something 3`.

You should use the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector) instead:

```
$('#myList ul:first > li:last').addClass('cool')
```